# Switch statement not working with multiple cases

Tags: php, html, switch-statement

I have a switch statement that is "linked", for lack of a better term, to a onClick event. When there is one case in the switch, it works. When all four cases are active, none of them work. Thank you for any help/suggestions, it is **truly** appreciated.

Code below:

**PHP File (mapcontroller.php):**

```
function playerMove($direction) 
{
    Global $mysqli;

    $sqlMoveNorth = "UPDATE ss_character SET coord_y = coord_y + 1  WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['usr']."'";
    $sqlMoveSouth = "UPDATE ss_character SET coord_y = coord_y - 1  WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['usr']."'";
    $sqlMoveEast = "UPDATE ss_character SET coord_x = coord_X + 1  WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['usr']."'";
    $sqlMoveWest = "UPDATE ss_character SET coord_x = coord_X - 1  WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['usr']."'";

    switch ($direction)
    {
        case "north":
            mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlMoveNorth);
            break;

        case "south":
            mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlMoveSouth);
            break;

        case "east":
            mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlMoveEast);
            break;

        case "west":
            mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlMoveWest);
            break;

        default:
            echo "Pick something!";
            break;
    }
}
```

**HTML File (travel.inc.php):**

```
<div class="map-wrapper">

    <?php $currentPage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

    <div class="map-move-container">
        <div class="map-move-north"><a onclick="<?php playerMove(north); ?>" href="<?php $currentPage ?>"> Move North</a></div>
        <div class="map-move-west"><a onclick="<?php playerMove(west); ?>" href="<?php $currentPage ?>"> Move West</a></div>
        <div class="map-move-east"><a onclick="<?php playerMove(east); ?>"  href="<?php $currentPage ?>"> Move East</a></div>
        <div class="map-move-south"><a onclick="<?php playerMove(south); ?>"  href="<?php $currentPage ?>"> Move South</a></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you can't put a PHP function into onclick, it's for javascript.

Comment: @kennypu If this is the case, I am not sure how I can move on with this without connecting to the database via JavaScript, which I know is a big security issue. Any suggestion on how to move forward?

Comment: it's not really a "big security issue", what it should do is 1. onclick, send an ajax request to php script that updates the player's position 2. (assuming this is a game) update page to show changes.

Comment: so JS isn't necessarily connecting to the database, you're just sending a ajax request to a PHP script, which will handle the database connection and updating etc.

Comment: @kennypu Awesome, I definitely will do that. Would you mind opening a chat? I have a few questions that are better answer in a chat. If you don't mind, that is.

Comment: Also...don't use 4 queries.   Just send an x/y change to php

Comment: ^ now that would be a security risk. what if I just send custom coordinates?

Comment: @JoshMiller http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25570/switch-statement-not-working-with-multiple-cases

Comment: This whole thing is a security risk with the unsanitized $_SESSION['usr'] = Little Bobby Tables, so let's not comment too much on security implications. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_poisoning

Comment: I mean send the delta via ajax.  If you want to lock down movement cap the change to +- 1

Answer (score 0):

The code will not work any way. As PHP is server side language and you are trying to use it on the user interference that's not possible.

The correct approach is onclick send the ajax request to get results. You can use jquery and many famous JS framewok.